# Position a Div to the center of a page

Tags: css, html

i have following background on my page :

[image]

it is  picture of old tbillisi,here is also my code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style>

#links { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 4800px; 
    font-size:70px;
    clear: both; 
    display: block;

}
#test a {
    float: right;
}
a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<body background="თბილისი.jpg" >


</body>
</html>
```

i want to add some links to my page, like 'hotels', 'tours' and 'entertainment' so that they dont appear to be on the houses etc. Id like them in the middle or on the right hand side. Could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Position your "links" div to where you want the links to be displays using tour CSS. Move the div around using margins or padding. Other way to position your div could be to float it left or right.

```
#links { 
    margin-top: 400px;//moves div down, this will probably be below the middle of the page 
    width: 4800px; 
    font-size:70px;
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much guys,just out of question,it is nice background right?

Answer (score 1):

You already positioning your links (`#links`, not in the code) in the center of the page. You should reduce the width to see an effect. Try `width: 950px;` or `width: 60em; max-width: 90%;`.

Another option would be to absolutely position your links-element (I assume it will be a list).

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="links-container">
    <a href="http://hostel.com>Super Hotel</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#links-container {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body background="http://www.cyprusq.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/NORTH-CYPRUS-HOTELS-view.jpg" >
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Hotel</a></li>
<li><a href="">Tours</a></li>
<li><a href="">Entertainment</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<style>
nav {
width: 300px;
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
}

nav li a{
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px;
color: #fff;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>​
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya4Ra/1/